# F5 BigIQ communication with BigIP

Tags: network, networking, load-balancer, f5

I'm new to `F5`. Basically a `BigIQ` centrally manages `BigIP` load balancers. In order to update the device, I have to login to the UI and apply the changes there. I would like to know how this is done (maybe through API?!) and how I can automate it.

Is there a set of API to automatically configure and update `BigIP` devices in-code (as opposed to `BigIQ`'s UI)? Is there a sample or template code for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F5 has a REST API available, documentation and examples can be found on https://devcentral.f5.com. If you have some programming skills, writing some scripts in python to do things isn't that hard.

Another way to manage them is by using [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/integrations/networks/f5). I haven't tried that myself (since I wrote my F5 management scripts before the Ansible modules were available), but I would most certainly look into that if I would have to automate F5 devices at this moment.

Comment: Great. That API if I can use in Python, would be great. So I can use them to create new BigIPs, update them, etc. Right?

Comment: I’ve only provisioned vips, pools, nodes and certificates, but as far as I’m aware the API should cover all functionality the webinterface offers.